# Why are my SQL*Plus results only allowing comma separated results?

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, sqlplus

I am trying to run a basic shell script to query my Oracle database and give me back results with a pipe | delimiter versus a comma.

No matter what I try it only returns with commas. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
sqlplus -s $DBUSER/$DBPASS@$DBCONN/$DBSID <<EOF
set colsep '|'
set echo off
@$SCRIPT_PATH/QRY_1.SQL
exit;
EOF
```

Comment: `set colsep` is OK. What does the .SQL script do? Does it "reset" colsep, by any chance?

Comment: Wow, I am an idiot. That was exactly it. Thank you!